# Data Transforming/formatting in Python

Tags: python, pandas, format

I've the following panda data:

```
df = {'ID_1': [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4],
      'ID_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'd', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z']
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
display(df)

ID_1    ID_2
1   a
1   b
1   c
2   f
2   g
3   d
4   v
4   x
4   y
4   z
```

For each `ID_1`, I need to find the combination (order doesn't matter) of `ID_2`. For example,

When `ID_1` = 1, the combinations are `ab, ac, bc`.
When `ID_1` = 2, the combination is `fg`.

Note, if the frequency of `ID_1`<2, then there is no combination here (see `ID_1`=3, for example).

Finally, I need to store the combination results in `df2` as follows:

[image]

Comment: Why isn't `b` to `c` in df2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way using `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

def comb_df(ser):
    return pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(ser, 2)), columns=["from", "to"])

new_df = df.groupby("ID_1")["ID_2"].apply(comb_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  from to
0    a  b
1    a  c
2    b  c
3    f  g
4    v  x
5    v  y
6    v  z
7    x  y
8    x  z
9    y  z
```